# JOIN two SELECTs with Doctrine

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I need to write this query with Doctrine. How can I write it down using QueryBuilder?

```
SELECT charges.id, charges.currency, charges.total_transactions, 
charges.total_volume, charges.commission, refunds.total_payouts
FROM
(SELECT ...very long query...) charges
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT ...very long query...) refunds
ON charges.id = refunds.id AND charges.currency = refunds.currency
```

Comment: You can use the [query-builder](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html) to create this query.

Comment: @thhan, I can't find there any info for my case. Only for SELECT from table (entity), not from two joined SELECTs. If you know how to do this, can you provide an example?

Comment: You can use two previous queryBuilders as source for your `from`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Native SQL](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html) and map results to entities:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\ResultSetMapping;

$rsm = new ResultSetMapping;
$rsm->addEntityResult('AppBundle:Charges', 'charges')
    ->addEntityResult('AppBundle:Refunds', 'refunds')
    ->addFieldResult('charges', 'id', 'id')
    ->addFieldResult('charges', 'currency', 'currency')
    ->addFieldResult('charges', 'total_transactions', 'total_transactions')
    ->addFieldResult('charges', 'total_volume', 'total_volume')
    ->addFieldResult('charges', 'commission', 'commission')
    ->addFieldResult('refunds', 'total_payouts', 'total_payouts')
;

$sql = " 
    SELECT
        charges.id,
        charges.currency,
        charges.total_transactions,
        charges.total_volume,
        charges.commission,
        refunds.total_payouts
    FROM
        (SELECT ...very long query...) charges
    LEFT JOIN
        (SELECT ...very long query...) refunds ON charges.id = refunds.id AND charges.currency = refunds.currency
    WHERE some_field = ?
";

$query = $this->getEntityManager()->createNativeQuery($sql, $rsm);
$query->setParameter(1, $name);
$entities = $query->getResult();
```

Comment: Thx, man. I think this is the only possible solution with Doctrine in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DQL` like this:

```
$dql = "SELECT ...";
$q = $entityManager->createQuery($dql)->setParameters($arrayParameters);
$result = $q->execute();
```

or `QueryBuilder` for each sub-query, like:

```
// subquery 1
$subQuery1 = $entityManager->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select('...')
    ->from('...')
    ->getDQL()
;
// subquery 2
$subQuery2 = ...
// etc
// ...
// main query
$query = $entityManager->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select('...')
    ->from('...', $subQuery1)
    ->leftJoin('...', $subQuery1->getDQL()),
    ->where()
;
```

PS: I just try provide gist for you... hope now you have clue...

Comment: Are you sure that the solution with `QueryBuilder` can work? Because when I execute generated query it throws the exception that  "Class 'SELECT' is not defined on col 195" right where the main query `FROM` tries to use subQuery1 (... FROM SELECT ...).

Answer (score 0):

Now I found out that it's impossible.

> Comment created by stof:
>
> DQL is about querying objects. Supporting subselects in the FROM clause means that the DQL parser is not able to build the result set mapping anymore (as the fields returned by the subquery may not match the object anymore).
>
> This is why it cannot be supported (supporting it only for the case you run the query without the hydration is a no-go IMO as it would mean that the query parsing needs to be dependant of the execution mode).
>
> In your case, the best solution is probably to run a SQL query instead (as you are getting a scalar, you don't need the ORM hydration anyway)

Source: https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/issues/3542